# How to show user profile image in asp.net mvc5 layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2

In my application i want to show user profile image in layout page (_LoginPartial).In database their is a student table which has a userid field that is maintain the relationship between AspNetUser table.Student table has the image field.So How to show that image in Layout page (_LoginPartial) view.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Please post example code for what you have already tried so we can guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using following steps

1. After valid login return to partial view same time return your profile image using model binding
2. In partial view you can use

   ```
   <img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ProfileImg)" alt="Image" />
   ```